# How to disabled other check-boxes if one check-box is checked after fetching data from database

Tags: javascript, c#

If page contains three check-boxes then I want to disable two checkbox if one checkbox is checked after fetching data from database using asp.net and javascript

Comment: Shouldn't you use a radio control instead? If you only want the ability to check one box, it seems that a radio control is the better option. If you're adamant that you want to disable, you'll need to follow the principles in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362284/uncheck-a-checkbox-if-another-checked-with-javascript#answer-19362379 instead of unchecking, you'll disable them

Answer (score 0):

use promise fetch:

```
const checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
const checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
const checkbox3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3");

fetch("www.yourapi.com?get-data").then((response) => {
  const checkbox1Checked = response.checkbox1;
  const checkbox2Checked = response.checkbox2;
  const checkbox3Checked = response.checkbox3;
  if (checkbox1Checked) {
    checkbox2.checked = false
    checkbox3.checked = false
  } else if (checkbox2Checked) {
    checkbox1.checked = false
    checkbox3.checked = false
  } else if (checkbox3Checked) {
    checkbox2.checked = false
    checkbox3.checked = false
  }
})
```