# How to only check one checkbox in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have figured out how to create a set of checkboxes but now I am challenged with creating a setting where the user can only choose one of the checkboxes.

I have looked online to try and find some alternative code to try and have found nothing.

```
            function printChecked(){
                var items=document.getElementsByName('acs');
                var selectedItems="";
                for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                    if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked)
                        selectedItems+=items[i].value+"\n";

                }

                alert(selectedItems);
            }
        <h1>Select which delimiter you want to use.</h1>
        <big>Select either TSV or CSV: </big><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="acs" value="CSV">CSV<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="acs" value="TSV">TSV<br>
        <p>
            <input type="button" onclick='printChecked()' value="Print Selected Items" /input>
        </p>
```

You can choose one or the other, both or neither. I want to option to be one or the other.

Comment: In this case you should use radio button instead.

Comment: That is why radios are made. use them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncheck a checkbox if another checked with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362284/uncheck-a-checkbox-if-another-checked-with-javascript)

Comment: Other people are correct to say use radio buttons. However, if your boss is insisting they look like checkboxes, you could style the radio buttons as checkboxes using css. Let me know if you want an example and I will post an answer. This would be better than using checkboxes and javascript per Akin's answer.

Comment: @MarkFisher IMO this is still very anti-user - it's confusing because it goes against what everyone else uses checkboxes for (and what they should be used for). It's also bad for the website's owner because it makes it harder to use. I see no value in this. If it's indeed the case that this requirement comes from a non-developer doing some excessive solutionising without the benefit of any UX or technical knowledge, then it's better in the long run to convince them to drop the idea, otherwise they'll just do it again. Not to mention they shouldn't be specifying to that level of detail anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the radio in this case. Why are you trying to use checkbox instead?

Comment: Not only is this the proper use for a radio button, but people would most likely be confused if given a set of check-boxes but can only select one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider whether you've ever seen this implemented in any website or application you've ever used? No? Can you remember what was used instead?

Use the right tool for the job: radio buttons or a drop down list are probably the most appropriate UI elements to consider when you want the user to choose a single unique value from a list of options.

Checkboxes are appropriate for either a yes/no to a single value, or for specifying multiple options simultaneously.

Most users are familiar with this pattern of use and would probably be confused or frustrated if they came across a checkbox list where they were restricted to a single value - they would be assuming (from universal experience) that they ought to be able to select more than one option.

Answer (score 0):

Radio boxes will be the better design here.

 However, If you **insist** - you can hack checkboxes into radio box, by adding a listener to the checkboxes

```js
function cbChange(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        cbs[i].checked = false;
    }
    obj.checked = true;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5uUjj/

Comment: sure you could hack it but why bother? It'll just confuse the user anyway

Comment: Ive had two cases in which Stakeholders say they **must** be check boxes.. I often defer to those who pay me. Rather than argue **best practices**

Comment: I prefer to diplomatically convince them it will be better for their business if they follow my advice (since they are paying me not just to do as I'm told, but to provide the benefit of my technical expertise and experience). Usability, or lack of it, can win or lose you custom or make things more or less efficient - it would be a good argument to use in a case like this. But of course you should do whatever works for you :-)

Comment: Still working on my stateman skills. Heck my dev skills aren't up to where i want them lmao...